# Google Maps disappear when switching browser tabs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a webpage with a header and a side bar, the rest of the page is filled by a Google Map using Google Maps API V3. The page layout looks similar to that of the official Google Maps website.

**Problem:** When I load my website with the Google Maps, and switch to another browser tab and back again to my website, very often the Google Maps will disappear! I have a button that involves resizing the Google map based on height/width of several divs, and pressing that button causes the Google Maps to appear again. How can I solve this disappearing Gmaps problem?

**Gmap Loading Code Snippet**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;

function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.354183,-71.065063);
    var options = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);
}
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is not with the code shown.. Can you supply a jsfiddle or something?

Comment: Let me try... the variables are fed through JSONs and I have to give some values to the variables. There are 100 markers on the page, if that helps